# ArrayList in Arraylist remove method behavior

Tags: java, arraylist, remove-method

I have an arraylist that looks like:

```
private ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> matrix = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>(9);
```

It is filled with these elements:

```
[[7], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [9]]
```

Now i want to remove the "1" from the second index so my wanted output is:

```
[[7], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [9]]
```

But when I use the remove method in the form:

```
matrix.get(1).remove(0);
```

The output is:

```
[[7], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [3], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [4], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [9]]
```

You can see that every "1" in all the ArrayLists of the main ArrayList is removed, instead of only at the second index. How can I change my code so only the "1" of the second index is removed?

Comment: Please post your code for creation of those arraylists and insertion of data into them

Comment: It was indeed a bad reference thank you for suggestion to look at the creation of the Arraylist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you store the same `ArrayList` instance in outer `ArrayList`:

```
outerList = [instance1, instance2, instance2, instance2, ...]
```

When you delete 1st element from instance2, change is visible in all other indexes.

If you want to avoid these issue, you should create new instance for every sub-list and copy elements from original list.

Answer (score 2):

Probably `matrix` contains several references to the same `ArrayList` (containing [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]).

Answer (score 0):

You are running into the difference between references and instances here.

When you added the child `ArrayList`s into the first one what you actually do is store a reference into the list, that reference then points to an `ArrayList`.

Note that its even legal (but definitely not recommended) for an `ArrayList` with the right type specified (for example `ArrayList<?>` ) to have a reference to itself inserted into the list!

If you store the same `ArrayList` multiple times then it will copy and create multiple *references* but those references will still point to the same *Object*.

You need to create a new `ArrayList` (using `new` or something like `clone()` in order to create the child `ArrayLists` and then add the new lists into the original.